# Is there a way to force GMail/Google Apps SMTP server to not store sent messages?

Tags: smtp, gmail, google-apps

Perhaps a special command or message header in order to be able to tell Google to not store a message sent using their SMTP server in the respective user's Sent mailbox.

Comment: I doubt it.  Consider using a service like Mailgun or SendGrid in addition to Google Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stucked in this kind of scenario some time back, for me I could not find any standard API to solve this. But as a workaround I have created a `rule` which deletes all the mails which appears in `Sent Folder`. But beware of IMAP protocol, it allows users to store their there sent messages in custom folders also.

Comment: Great ! And you have even month history in trash :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent the message from being saved to Sent. However, you can connect via IMAP after the send and delete the message from the Sent folder. Assuming you are using OAuth authentication, the same scope you use for SMTP allows you to connect via IMAP.